# Bigquery - Repeated String

Tags: google-bigquery

I splat a string and now I want to use the output, but I get the error as the `split`-output is considered `Repeated Sting` and therefore `ARRAY`.

How can I work around it?

Thanks

```
With ex1 as (
SELECT 'test1,test2' as example
),

ex2 as (
SELECT 'test1' as str1, 5 as value)

SELECT * 
from

(SELECT split(example,',') as strings
from ex1)

left join 
    ex2
on str1 = strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to UNNEST the result of split:

```
WITH 
ex1 AS (
SELECT 'test1,test2' as example),
ex2 AS (
SELECT 'test1' as str1, 5 as value)
SELECT * from
(SELECT * FROM UNNEST((SELECT split(example) FROM ex1)) as strings)
left join 
    ex2
on str1 = strings
```

Answer (score 3):

You should [`UNNEST`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/exploring-a-powerful-sql-pattern-array-agg-struct-and-unnest-b7dcc6263e36/) the array before using it in your `LEFT JOIN` :

```
With ex1 as (
SELECT 'test1,test2' as example
),
ex2 as (
SELECT 'test1' as str1, 5 as value)
SELECT  *
from
UNNEST ((SELECT split(example,',') as strings
from ex1
)) as strings
left join 
ex2
on str1 = strings
```